# Input clears on each useEffect render

Tags: reactjs

[image]

In the above UI, the Input field clears on each re-render (i.e each time data changes in useEffect).

```
  useEffect(() => {
    display();
  }, [data]);
```

The data needs to be dependent because on **Delete and Add** the UI must re-render to show the changes.
Initially, the "Hello Red" shows in the input field but on deleting any number range (eg:3 and 4), the input field clears out.

**Partial Code:**

```
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    Red: {
      Name: "R",
      List: [
        ["4", "6"],
        ["3", "4"],
        ["1", "2"],
        ["7", "10"]
      ]
    }
  });

  const deleteNewRange = (key) => {
    console.log(key);
    let obj = { ...data };
    data.Red.List.splice(key, 1);
    obj = {
      ...data,
      Red: {
        ...data.Red,
        Name: data.Name,
        List: [...data.Red.List]
      }
    };
    setData(obj);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    display(); //display code can be found in below codesandbox link
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <>
      <Form>
        {data.Red.List.map((range, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <Form.Item name={"startRange" + index}>
              <InputNumber />
            </Form.Item>
            <p>To</p>
            <Form.Item name={"endRange" + index}>
              <InputNumber/>
            </Form.Item>
              <div>
                Add
              </div>
              <div onClick={() => deleteNewRange(index)}>
                Delete
              </div>
            </div>
        ))}
      </Form>
      <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
        Save
      </Button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Link to more code and other functions and object conversion: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd-4-16-9-forked-dq9ngr?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Your `display` function is an anti-pattern, and goes against the way react reasons about state and rendering.

You want to use a pattern called "controlled components". Basically, your form `values` should all be using your state, and on form change you update your state. You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

Comment: Yeah but range doesn't have a fixed state name to useState.
`<Form.Item name={"startRange" + index}>` it can be startRange0,1,2....

Answer (score 0):

it's because you have added dependency of whole state you just to add for `list'  try this.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    display();
  }, [data.list]);
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  Still on list change, it re-runs the useEffect